# why it print nothing when i want to show all files when type 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I am new to Python and now im studying about inheritance. I have a class name LibraryItem which is filled with books and magazine, I already add them manually using this

```
def new_book(self):
    self.libraryitems.append(Book("The Fault in Our Stars", "Fiction", "asdasd", "John Green", "012012", "D12"))
```

But when I type 1 to print all books it returns nothing in CMD and invalid in IDLE. is there anything wrong with my code ?

when I want to show the libraryitems using 1 :

```
def show_libraryitems(self, libraryitems=None):
    if not libraryitems:
        libraryitems = self.Catalog.libraryitems
    for Book in libraryitems:
        print("{0}: {1}\n{2}".format(libraryitem.title, libraryitem.subject))
```

Here is the full code

This is the Menu Class

```
import sys
from LibraryItem import LibraryItem, Catalog, Book, Magazine, DVD

class Menu:
    '''Display a menu and respond to choices when run.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.Catalog = Catalog()
        self.choices = {
                "1": self.show_libraryitems,
                "2": self.search_libraryitems,
                "3": self.quit
                }

    def display_menu(self):
        print("""
Menu

1. Show all File
2. Search Library
3. Quit
""")

    def run(self):
        '''Display the menu and respond to choices.'''
        while True:
            self.display_menu()
            choice = input("Enter an option: ")
            action = self.choices.get(choice)
            if action:
                action()
            else:
                print("{0} is not a valid choice".format(choice))

    def show_libraryitems(self, libraryitems=None):
        if not libraryitems:
            libraryitems = self.Catalog.libraryitems
        for libraryitem in libraryitems:
            print("{0}: {1}\n{2}".format(libraryitem.title, libraryitem.subject, libraryitem.contributor))

    def search_libraryitems(self):
        filter = input("Search for: ")
        libraryitems = self.Catalog.search(filter)
        self.show_libraryitems(libraryitems)

    def quit(self):
        print("Thank you for using LibraryItem")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Menu().run()
```

This is the LibraryItem Class

```
import datetime

last_id = 0

class LibraryItem:

    def __init__(self, title, subject, contributor=''):
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject
        self.contributor = contributor


    def match(self, filter):
        return filter in self.title or filter in self.subject

class Book(LibraryItem):
    def __init__(self, title, subject, contributor, author, isbn, dds_number=''):
        super().__init__(title, subject, contributor)
        self.author = author
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.dds_number = dds_number


class Magazine(LibraryItem):
    def __init__(self, title, subject, contributor, volume, issue=''):
        super().__init__(title, subject, contributor)
        self.volume = volume
        self.issue = issue
class DVD(LibraryItem):
    def __init__(self, title, subject, contributor, actors, director, genre=''):
        super().__init__(title, subject, contributor)
        self.director = director
        self.genre = genre

class Catalog:

    def __init__(self):
        self.libraryitems = []

    def new_book(self):
        self.libraryitems.append(Book("The Fault in Our Stars", "Fiction", "asdasd", "John Green", "012012", "D12"))
    def new_magazine(self):
        self.libraryitems.append(Magazine("VOGUE", "lifestyle", "asdasd", "name", "asd"))

    def search(self, filter):
        return [libraryitem for libraryitem in self.libraryitems if
                    libraryitem.match(filter)]
```

Comment: Hi Jin, please note that when pasting Python code preserving the correct indentation is very important.  Please edit your question to correct the indentation.  You can do this easily by copy/pasting your code verbatim into the editor, selecting the lines of code, and pressing Ctrl-K to indent it all simultaneously.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you tried and what you expected to happen.  It seems `self.Catalog.libraryitems` is an empty list by default, so it will print nothing.

Comment: @Iguananaut edited, thanks for the information !

Comment: Also is this Python 2 or Python 3?  You tagged your question with both.  Unfortunately that actually matters here because `input(...)` works very differently on Python 2.

Comment: @Iguananaut but In Catalog class, I insert the book there(def new_book(self):
        self.libraryitems.append(Book("The Fault in Our Stars", "Fiction", "asdasd", "John Green", "012012", "D12"))
  ). or am I wrong in doing it ? I want to insert the items manually in the code and when I run and press 1(show all) I want it to be shown there

Comment: `def new_book(self): ...` only defines a method.  Nowhere do I see you actually *call* that method.

Comment: @Iguananaut its python 2.7, sorry for that. so how can I print the book that I inserted in new_book when I type 1 in the menu option (show all). sorry im really new to python

Comment: Did you actually insert a new book though?  None of the code you posted shows that you actually *called* `Catalog.new_book` anywhere before running the menu.

Comment: For example, if you wanted your catalog to be pre-populated with some books for testing purposes, you might call `self.new_book()` in`Catalog.__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

On Python 2 you should use `raw_input`, not `input`.  Try it yourself to see:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct 31 2017, 21:12:13)
[GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = input('blah: ')
blah: 1
>>> x
1
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
```

On Python 2, `input(...)` takes the string you input and (unfortunately) passes it through `eval(...)` so you will return an `int` not a string.  You can test this yourself and see.

On Python 3 `input(...)` is the same as Python 2's `raw_input(...)`.  On Python 2, you should almost never use `input()`; this was considered a mistake that was corrected in Python 3.

That said, I'm confused because the rest of your code looked like Python 3.  For example, `super()` with no argument is Python 3 syntax.